# Merging 2 UIStoryBoards into one and keeping all the constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have an App that was built around iOS 6 now i have 2 UIStoryboards with the same content one for iPhone and one for iPad.

My question is can i somehow merge or unite these two storyboards into one while keeping all constraints and UI elements (button, labels, views and such) and all outlets connected into one modern storyboard?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think that you can use one of these storyboards and enable the size classes and autolayout.

Comment: What do you mean? Abd Aboudi

Comment: Ex : You can use iPad storyboard and enable the size classes to insure that its design is correct on the other layouts (iPhone).

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice.Abd Aboudi